# Cannot find function associated with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, alamofire

I have installed Alamofire and successfully built my app after 'import Alamofire' (command + B).  However, when I try to call one of the request functions, no 'request' functions associated with Alamofire exists (please see photo below).  Please can someone advise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write request to end with parameters, then build or run. There is nothing to worry. The error says, "Alamofire.request" is not fully written function.

Comment: can u remove the -1 from my question. i think it is a readonable question

Answer (score 0):

There is no

> no 'request' functions associated with Alamofire

error. You just click Tab at this moment, or write your function till the end. All the parameters, etc. Error will be resolved, even if there will be an developer placeholder